# What function to use to view database tables in R browser?

Tags: mysql, r, rstudio

```
server<-function(input,output,session) {
observeEvent(input$do, {
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "$$$$", uid = "$$$$", pwd = "$$$$")
result<-dbSendQuery(con,"select * from table_name")
data.frame<-dbFetch(result)
View(data.frame)
```

I have want the view the table in the R browser (not the console), so what function exactly need to use?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use `tableHTML` which would convert your data.frame into an HTML table to make it possible to view on RStudio's browser (or your browser):

As an example:

```
library(tableHTML)
tableHTML(mtcars)
```